# How do forward-looking forward rates in the Mercurio's and Lyashenko's normal or extended FMM model represent EURIBOR rates

Tags: interest-rates, libor, sofr, modelling, rfr

(By XIBOR I intend any EURIBOR or LIBOR rate. By RFR I intend SOFR for the USD and ESTR (€STR) for EUR.)

I am mainly focused on the EUR rates market (but also a bit on the USD market) and looking for a model able to price EURIBOR swaps, caps, floors, swaptions and EURIBOR exotics (callable or not) like TARNs, range accruals etc, as well as ESTR/SOFR linked (OIS) swaps and SOFR swaptions (until their EUR counterparts appear). To sum up, I need a model pricing vanilla XIBOR derivatives, XIBOR exotics (callable or not) as well as well as vanilla RFR derivatives (OIS swaps and swaptions, caps floors, RFR futures).

I came across Mercurio's and Lyashenko's FMM model and it's extended version (see their two SSRN papers) where they define backward-looking forward rates $R_j (t)$ and forward-looking forward rates $F_j (t)$ which, to quote their first paper, "*are set at the beginning of their application period. For instance, a forward-looking rate at time* $T_{j−1}$ *with maturity* $T_j$ *can be defined similarly to an OIS swap rate*".

First, unless I missed some big hypothesis of a constant spread between the forward-looking forward rate based on the RFR and the XIBOR rate (or more directly between the RFR the XIBOR rate), I don't see what link this $F_j (t)$ could have with a XIBOR. Second, this $F_j (t)$ *defined similarly to an OIS swap rate* conflicts with the introduction of their first paper where it's written that that *the classic interest rate modeling framework can be naturally extended to describe the evolution of both the forward-looking (IBOR-like) and backward-looking (setting-inarrears) term rates using the same stochastic process*.

For sure I am missing something (probably linked to some collateral) somewhere but I can't see what, or misunderstanding the "XIBOR-like" signification.

For sake of completeness, the SSRN links for the two papers :

[Looking Forward to Backward-Looking Rates: A Modeling Framework for Term Rates Replacing LIBOR](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3330240)

and

[Looking Forward to Backward-Looking Rates: Completing the Generalized Forward Market Model](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3482132)